# Progress bar explanation NetTrain

Tags: neural-networks

I was wondering what the progress window that appears when I call `NetTrain` is trying to tell me. There are 7 values given and one graph:

- round
- batch
- inputs/second (self explanatory)
- time elapsed time remaining (self explanatory)
- batch loss
- round loss
- a graph with no y-axis

I could not find anything in the mathematica documentation and was wondering if anyone knows.

Best,
Max

Comment: The batch loss is the loss in one batch. The plot is showing the batch loss (cost function) as a function of number of batches trained. After one batch around finished, there will be a blue dot added to the plot showing the round loss.

Comment: thank you! And what does round x/y mean?

Comment: Please see the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a typical training plot

[image]

Here is a list of what these means:

- Round 3/3: 3 total rounds and currently at the 3rd round. The 3 total rounds mean that each input in the training set will be visited approximately 3 times. This number can be set by `MaxTrainingRounds`.
- 381/938: 938 batches in this round and currently at the 381th bach
- time elapsed: time elapsed in training
- time remaining: remaining time of training
- batch loss: the loss for the current batch
- round loss: the loss for the last round
- validation loss: the loss for validation set. This can be useful to identify overfitting/underfitting.

The orange line in the plot shows the loss as a function of the number of batches trained. The loss represents the error between the actual output and predicted output of the input. The decreasing of the loss means that the model is converging. The blue dashed line shows the validation loss as a function of rounds.